# Update using PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am still getting my head around a PDO statement but the code below does not do what I assumed it would

```
  $temp = "6c ";    
  $weather_report = "Its currently $temp " ; 

  $qry = $pdo->exec("UPDATE data_weather SET text= '$weather_report' WHERE period='report' ");
```

This does update my database but only with 'Its currently' and the temp value is missing ,

After reading some articles I believe I need to use quote but I am not sure how to implement it ?

any help please ?

Comment: what's the type/size of the `text` field?

Comment: You need to read up on [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) and make a point to never, **ever** insert arbitrary user data into your query strings. Seeing `$weather_report` inside a query should set off alarm bells.

Comment: you should use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use query parameters instead of interpolating variables into SQL strings.
It's safer, faster, and easier.

```
$temp = "6c ";    
$weather_report = "It's currently $temp " ; 

$sql = "UPDATE data_weather SET text= ? WHERE period='report'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($weather_report));
```

Note that you don't need to quote the string.  In fact, you *must not* put quotes around the `?` placeholder.  You can use apostrophes inside your weather report string safely.

You can use a parameter placeholder any place you would normally put a single scalar value in an SQL expression.  E.g. in place of a quoted string, quoted date, or numeric literal.  But not for table names or column names, or for lists of values, or SQL keywords.

Comment: Thanks for that Bill, I was unsure of declaring $weather_report as an array ?

Comment: The PDOStatement::execute() function requires its argument to be an array, so you can pass multiple parameters to the SQL query.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter, please let me know what you feel is not right in this answer, so I can try to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

Although Bill has already answered the question, I'd like to add:

**Do not use named parameters with TEXT columns, at least not with MySQL. It won't work. Use question marks instead.**

Comment: Would you please kindly delete your misleading comment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Check it on PHP forums. It is a true bug many have experienced, but it may have already been solved.

Comment: Many have experienced an aliens' visits as well.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I do understand that it may sound like an aliens' visit, but I have truly experienced it. I admit that PHP is not my cup of coffee and the problem might have been elsewhere, but using '?' instead of named parameters solved my problem at the time. I am willing to delete my answer the very moment you provide an evidence that it isn't so. I would have done it myself already if I had had an appropriate workspace.